# Make jar of my selenium- Maven project and handover to the stakeholders to execute from their end

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, executable-jar

I want to export my project to an executable jar with all the dependencies attached

so that any stakeholder can doubleclick on the jar to execute the scripts
in order to achieve I have created a class(Main) file from which I will execute my testng xml file

My pom looks like below where I have provided the main class file in assembly plugin

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>SikuliWindowsApp</groupId>
<artifactId>SikuliWindowsApp_V1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>SikuliWindowsApp_V1</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.2gis.winium</groupId>
        <artifactId>winium-webdriver</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>SikuliWindowsApp.SikuliWindowsApp_V1.EntryPoint</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

using assembly command I am able to get the jar file in my target location but if i double click the jar is not getting executed

Comment: So what happens when you try to start the jar?

Comment: nothing is happening and I don't see any task in task manager also

Comment: Start the jar on the command line and copy/paste the error message to this question.

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class SikuliWindowsApp.SikuliWindowsApp_V1.EntryPoint but the EntryPoint class is available in the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpack the jar (with an unzipping tool) and look for the class `EntryPoint`. Make sure that the path exactly reflects the packaging (not typos, not upper/lower case, nothing missing).

If the EntryPoint class is not there, check that the source of the class is indeed in `src/main/java` in your project. You can also check in the `target` folder for that class.

Comment: I am getting this error nowException in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG
        at SikuliWindowsApp.SikuliWindowsApp_V1.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more

Comment: This is a different error, and you should ask a new question for that. In that question you need to add the source code of `EntryPoint.java`

Comment: I am okay with your answer and I voted up here is my Entrypoint.java

Comment: Please write a new question. Questions should not be answered in comments and source code in comments is hard to read (let alone the fact that I cannot find out what line 23 is).

Comment: I extracted the jar and I do not find any testng class files after extracting could you please suggest

Comment: Let me repeat myself: Write a new question. Do not add further comments.